# parent item drop up with sub menu

Tags: html, css

hello is it possible that when I hover to the parent item the parent item will also slide up making the drop down menu with parent item above it? here is my code but I cant seem to make it work. here is a visual menu that i want https://i.stack.imgur.com/MtJzo.jpg (the second image)

```css
        .nav ul {

          *zoom: 1;

          list-style: none;

          margin: 0;

          padding: 0;

          background: #333;

        }

        .nav ul:before,

        .nav ul:after {

          content: "";

          display: table;

        }

        .nav ul:after {

          clear: both;

        }

        .nav ul > li {

          float: left;

          position: relative;

        }

        .nav a {

          display: block;

          padding: 10px 20px;

          line-height: 1.2em;

          color: #fff;

          border-left: 1px solid #595959;

        }

        .nav a:hover {

          text-decoration: none;

          background: #595959;

        }

        .nav li ul {

          background: #273754;

          position: absolute;

          left: 0;

          bottom: 36px;

          z-index: 1;

        }

        .nav li ul li {

          width: 100%;

          overflow: hidden;

          height: 0;

          -webkit-transition: height 200ms ease-in;

          -moz-transition: height 200ms ease-in;

          -o-transition: height 200ms ease-in;

          transition: height 200ms ease-in;

        }

        .nav li ul a {

          border: none;

        }

        .nav li ul a:hover {

          background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);

        }

        .nav ul > li:hover ul li {

          height: 36px;

        }
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Nav Item</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Subnav</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subnav</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subnav</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Nav Item</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Subnav</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subnav</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Subnav</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this css to your already existing code. Is this what you wanted?

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jbBgdg

```
li>ul {
  display: none;
}
a:hover~ul {
  display: block;
}
```

Comment: hello sir, thank for replying, this is what i want, for the parent item menu to go with the sub menu when hovered, is this possible attached here is a visual image: http://imgur.com/om9mvdG

Comment: Which one do you want 1st or 2nd?
" for the parent item menu to go with" to go where? On top or on bottom?

Comment: the 2nd sir! , the "Nav Item" to at the top when hovered together with the sub menu.

Comment: i have a sample site sir, it is almontasser.com i would like to have menu like the one below the slider, is it possible? sorry for my english. :)